# Java replace/replaceAll strange behavior

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I can't get what I'm missing here. Both `replace` and `replaceAll` from `java.lang.String` are generating a question mark (?) after each ocurrence:

```
        String str = "ABCD DKABCED DLS ABC";        
        System.out.println("str='"+str+"'");
        System.out.println("str.replaceAll(\"ABC\", \"A\\\\${BC}​\" ) => " + str.replaceAll("ABC", "A\\${BC}​" ));
        System.out.println("str.replace(\"ABC\", \"A${BC}​\" ) => " + str.replace("ABC", "A${BC}​" ));
```

Generates the following output:

```
str='ABCD DKABCED DLS ABC'
str.replaceAll("ABC", "A\\${BC}?" ) => A${BC}?D DKA${BC}?ED DLS A${BC}?
str.replace("ABC", "A${BC}?" ) => A${BC}?D DKA${BC}?ED DLS A${BC}?
```

Here an image of the execution:
[image]

Does anybody knows why?

EDITED:

Just for the record. The problem it that there really WAS a character after the brackets.
After coping and pasting to Notepad++ I could see the `}?"`text. Not in Netbeans.
So purelly enconding missunderstanding.

Comment: You've totally changed the code in the question. The output no longer matches the code.

Comment: What happens when you remove `$`?

Comment: Nothing, the problem is with the } character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a character encoding problem. When I pasted your code into Eclipse (on Windows) it could not save the code, complaining about the character set:

> Some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding.

When I retyped it in from scratch, the problem went away:

```
String str = "ABCD DKABCED DLS ABC";
System.out.println("str='" + str + "'");
System.out.println(str.replace("ABC", "A${BC}"));
```

produces the following (without extra ? marks):

```
str='ABCD DKABCED DLS ABC'
A${BC}D DKA${BC}ED DLS A${BC}
```

If you take the [hexdump](https://hexdump.pieterhordijk.com/) of a normal `}` you get `7d`.

But for the `}` character in your code, I get `7d e2 80 8b`

Comment: That is it! I copied the String I wanted to replace from an e-mail, I couldn't see that there was an invisible character. After copying and pasting it to Notepad++ I found it. Was driving me crazy xD Thanks anyway. Sorry for the meaningless question.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because you have question marks in your replacement string. Thus `replace` and `replaceAll` are simply doing exactly what you are telling them to do.

Comment: What?? just realized the System.out.println also generated a question mark!! Look at the code, there is no question mark there!

Comment: It does not generate a question mark on my machine. Ensure that you saved your foreign characters as UTF-8 encoding.